# CS50 Pset1 Credit ... Can someone please explain why does the program not working. I searched everywhere there is no solution that is using functions

Tags: c, cs50

CS50 PSET1 Credit - https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2022/psets/1/credit/
Well known problem in CS50 commmunity so not going to post the full problem here.

I intend to solve the problem using different functions instead of writing everything inside main which is what i have been finding for hours .

If anyone have solution for this problem using diferent functions for everystep please share in answers.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

long get_credit_number(void);
int checksum(long cn);



// Driver code
int main(void)
{
   int valid = 1;
   long cn = get_credit_number();
   int cm = checksum(cn);



   long ccn = cn;
   int length = 0;
   long divisor = 10;
   int first_digit; int first_twodigit;


    if (cm == valid)
    {
        // Check length of credit card number
        while (ccn > 0)
       {
            ccn = ccn % 10;
            length++;
        }
        // Check first two digits of credit card number
        for (int i = 0; i < length - 2; i++)
        {
            divisor = divisor * 10;
        }
        first_digit = ccn/divisor;
        first_twodigit = ccn / (divisor / 10);

        // check whether card is AMEX
        if (length == 15 && (first_twodigit == 34 || first_twodigit == 37))
        {
            printf("AMEX\n");
        }
        // check whether card is MASTERCARD
        else if (length == 16 && (first_twodigit > 50 && first_twodigit == 56))
        {
            printf("MASTERCARD\n");
        }
        //check whether card id VISA
        else if ((length == 13 || length == 16) && first_digit == 4)
        {
            printf("VISA");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
    }


}


// Prompt user to enter the credit card number
long get_credit_number(void)
{
    long cna;
    do
    {
       cna = get_long("Number: ");
    }
    while (cna <= 0);
    return cna;
}

// Checksum by Luhm algorithm
int checksum(long cn)
{
    int sum = 0;
    long cna;
    long ccn = cn;

    while (ccn > 0)
    {
        cna = cn % 10;
        sum = sum + cna ;
        ccn = ccn / 100;
    }

    ccn = ccn/10;
    long cnb;

    while (ccn > 0)
    {
        cna = ccn % 10;
        cnb = 2 * cna;
        sum = sum + (cnb%10) + (cnb/10);
        ccn = ccn / 100;
    }


    sum = sum % 10;
    if (sum == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2022/psets/1/credit/

Comment: For numbers that have a fixed length and possible leading zeros, like phone-numbers or credit-card numbers, don't use plain integers. The leading zeros will not be preserved.

Comment: Also note that `long` is signed and could be 32-bits, which means it will not store values above about 2 billion. That will not be able to handle the 16 digits of a normal credit-card number.

Comment: The solution to both above problems is *arrays*. Either of the digits as characters, or of the digits as integers (your choice).

Comment: Cant use arrays as arrays are beyond the scope of this problem since its week 1 problem. And i dont think long here is the problem since many solutions that are already available on internet are using long.

Comment: If you can't use proper data types, at least take `unsigned long long`. That doesn't solve any leading zero problem but should be large enough.

Comment: `ccn`, `cna`, `cnb`, `cn`... Do yourself any everyone around you a favor and avoid using such meaningless identifiers. Being too lazy to type proper names is not a good start for programming.

Comment: In `checksum`: After the first `while (ccn > 0)` loop, `ccn` must be zero or less. `ccn = ccn/10;` will still be zero or less, and thus the next `while (ccn > 0)` will never run. `sum` and `sum % 10` may then be inaccurate. I haven't bothered to checked the correctness of the loop bodies. This also prints *INVALID* twice.

Comment: Note that you can (see: should) use arrays if you understand how, as it is the correct tool for the task at hand. CS50's grading program does not care how you arrive at a solution, just that your program's output matches an expectation set by a given input. The style checker also does not care about the semantics of your program, only certain syntax and formatting. That said, `long` *is* a large enough type on CS50's online platform to hold a CCN - its just a poor choice for exactly the reason they instruct you to use a `long` instead of an `int` - it won't be large enough on all platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this solution here for future cs50 students. I solved the problem by dividing the problem into three different functions and completely avoided using global variables.Hope this help someone in future.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Functions Declaration
long get_credit_number(void);
long checksum(long credit_number);
void finalcheck(long check_sum, long credit_number);


// Driver code
int main(void)
{
    // Calling the Functions
    long credit_number = get_credit_number();
    long check_sum = checksum(credit_number);
    finalcheck(check_sum, credit_number);
}



// Prompt user to enter the credit card number
long get_credit_number(void)
{
    long credit_num;
    do
    {
        credit_num = get_long("Number: ");
    }
    while (credit_num <= 0);
    return credit_num;
}


// Checksum by Luhm algorithm
long checksum(long credit_number)
{
    long sum = 0;
    long last_digit;
    long credit_card_number = credit_number;
    // Luhm's algorithm Case 1
    while (credit_card_number > 0)
    {
        last_digit = credit_card_number % 10;
        sum = sum + last_digit ;
        credit_card_number = credit_card_number / 100;
    }

    credit_card_number = credit_number / 10;
    long two_times;
    // Luhm's algorithm Case 2
    while (credit_card_number > 0)
    {
        last_digit = credit_card_number % 10;
        two_times = 2 * last_digit;
        sum = sum + (two_times % 10) + (two_times / 10);
        credit_card_number = credit_card_number / 100;
    }
    sum = sum % 10;
    // Check whether the last digit of sum is 0 or not
    if (sum == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

//Final check whether the card is Visa, Amex, Mastercard or Invalid
void finalcheck(long check_sum, long credit_number)
{
    long valid_cc = credit_number;
    int length = 0;
    long divisor = 10;
    int first_digit;
    int first_twodigit;

    if (check_sum == 1)
    {
        // Check length of credit card number
        while (valid_cc > 0)
        {
            valid_cc = valid_cc / 10;
            length++;
        }

        // Check first two digits of credit card number
        valid_cc = credit_number;
        for (int i = 0; i < (length - 2); i++)
        {
            divisor = divisor * 10;
        }

        first_digit = valid_cc / divisor;
        first_twodigit = valid_cc / (divisor / 10);

        // check whether card is AMEX
        if (length == 15 && (first_twodigit == 34 || first_twodigit == 
        37))
        {
            printf("AMEX\n");
        }
        // check whether card is MASTERCARD
        else if (length == 16 && (first_twodigit == 50 && first_twodigit 
        << 56))
        {
            printf("MASTERCARD\n");
        }
        //check whether card id VISA
        else if ((length == 13 || length == 16) && first_digit == 4)
        {
            printf("VISA\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("INVALID\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
    }
}
```